# django-registration can't set the "from" email address for authentication email

Tags: python, django, default, django-registration

i've got django-registration setup and working with my application. I'm on django 1.1 and using the latest django-registration, 0.8 alpha.
in case it is relevant, i'm using the fcgi method to deploy and the django-registration app is deployed in a separate folder. I simply add the containing folder to python path. i.e. in settings.py of my app i do

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/django-registration-parent-folder')
```

in my settings file i have also set

```
DEFAULT_FROM_USER = 'email@address.that.should.be used'
```

When django registration sends out the activation email, however, it continues to be from

> webmaster@localhost

the only way i was able to change this was by changing the actual code inside of django-registration. i.e. in models.py line 254:

```
# self.user.email_user(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)
self.user.email_user(subject, message, 'email@address.that.should.be used')
```

Can anybody enlighten me as to why DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL in the settings file of my app is not being used when sending activation emails?

thanks in advance

Comment: This REALLY isn't localised. I had the same problem. Anyone using django-registration (the module most Django tutorials say to use) will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typo, you set `DEFAULT_FROM_USER` in your settings, but it should be `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`.

Comment: wow... that is eff-in embarrassing....thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The snippet from settings.py is `DEFAULT_FROM_USER` instead of `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`